# How to append FormData values and send them through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to send values using `form data` object to an `ajax` call and get the values using a `php` file, but apparently `form data` values are wrong.

Here is what I did. This is my `html`

```
<thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th class="text-center">Subject</th>
            <th class="text-center">Upload</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Physics 1</td>
            <td>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="file" onchange="changeColor(this, 'p1')" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" name="p1" id="p1" hidden>
                </label>
                <button type="button" onclick="uploadFileIAL('ial', 'Physics 1', 'p1')" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="removeFile('ial', 'Physics 1', 'p1')" id="p1" class="btn btn-danger" aria-expanded="false">X</button>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Physics 2</td>
            <td>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="file" onchange="changeColor(this, 'p2')" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" name="p2" id="p2" hidden>
                </label>
                <button type="button" onclick="uploadFileIAL('ial', 'Physics 2', 'p2')" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="removeFile('ial', 'Physics 1', 'p2')" id="p2" class="btn btn-danger" aria-expanded="false">X</button>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Physics 3</td>
            <td>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="file" onchange="changeColor(this, 'p3')" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" name="p3" id="p3" hidden>
                </label>
                <button type="button" onclick="uploadFileIAL('ial', 'Physics 3', 'p3')" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="removeFile('ial', 'Physics 3', 'p3')" id="p3" class="btn btn-danger" aria-expanded="false">X</button>
            </td>

        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is my `javascript ajax`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function uploadFileIAL(igcseOrIal, subject, fileid) {

    var data = new FormData();

    jQuery.each(jQuery('#p1')[0].files, function(i, file) { //this scope is not executing for some reason
        alert(i); //this is not printing, since scope is not executing
        data.append('file' + i, file);
        data.append('subject', subject);
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/upload-ial-pastpapers.php',
        dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data); //prints "error" from php file

            $("#" + fileid).val(null);
            // $("button[id='"+fileid+"']").hide();
            // $("#" + fileid).css({"backgroundColor": "", "color": ""});
        }
    });

}

</script>
```

and this is my `php` file

```
include_once './connection.php';

if (isset($_FILES['file0'])){ //this scope is not executing, gives undefined 'file0'

    echo 'ok';

    $file = $_FILES['file0'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file0']['name'];
    $fileTempName = $_FILES['file0']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file0']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file0']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file0']['type'];

    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    echo $subject;

    //uploadPhotos($conn, $fileName, $fileError, $fileSize, $fileTempName, $subject);


}else{
    echo "error"; //this part is executes and sends to `ajax` to alert();
}
```

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(jQuery('#p1')[0].files)`?

Comment: @tcj:  `FileList {length: 0}` this is the output

Comment: And when you select a file do you get the same? Because your file inputs are hidden thus its not possible to select a file unless you remove `hidden` attribute.